# Batch Script to Replace Filenames with Increasing Numbers to be Reverted Later

Tags: batch-file, filenames, long-filenames

I am attempting to write a series of scripts to copy a folder full of non-predetermined files and possibly subdirectories from a Windows 7/10 environment to a MS-DOS 7.0 environment (that's Windows 95 in DOS-Mode) running in Vanilla DOSBox 0.74-3. **The copy process, which cannot be worked around or changed, destroys long file names.** The software on the MS-DOS 7.0 end requires these long file names to run properly.

My plan is to have a Windows batch script with a simple `dir /b /on /s > lfn.txt` to keep track of all the long file names.

Then next step ideally, and here is where I am stumped, reads back through the lfn.txt and renames all the files from top to bottom to an increasing integer starting at 1 and never resetting. My goal is to be able to copy and tweak this script to work on MS-DOS where it does the reverse. If the solution, even conceptually, can be made *that* portable I would prefer that solution even if it is more verbose or inefficient.

I apologize if this has been asked and answered elsewhere. If it has please link to it before closing this thread.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think you could improve your chances of getting an answer if you review the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and modify your question.

Comment: The problem is that it's impossible to make a single script that will work across all platforms, ESPECIALLY if you add MS-DOS into the mix. You could simply use Python to make the script that will work on MacOS X, Windows, Ubuntu, etc, but MS-DOS is old, and to my knowledge, is will only run batch/command line files. It can't run any other programming language. And MacOS X and Ubuntu can't run batch, so it simply won't work. Unless you can somehow make a batch script that will also convert a Python script to a Batch script. That might be possible.